# How can I make my LaTeX paper look like this?

Tags: formatting, document-classes, resources

I've seen MANY papers created with LaTeX that have the following format:

[image]

[image]

In particular, I like the font sizes and the way that section titles are centered and in all caps. Does anyone know if there is a document class for this look? I'm sure there is something for it since I've seen so many papers that look exactly like this... Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `amsart`.

Comment: You can download the paper source from the arXiv. In this case they use `\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{amsart}`

Comment: What are the margins typically used on papers created using this class? Just the default ones or something special? I particularly like them on the second paper I posted.

Comment: the first example is almost certainly `amsart`, but the second one, if based on `amsart`, doesn't have the default dimensions or the default type style for the authors.  `amsart` has a default `30pc` width; the second example appears wider.  (changing the width on `amsart` is not completely trivial.)

Answer (score 13):

It's [`amsart`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart), a standard document class from the American Mathematical Society used in its journals and widely elsewhere, e.g., in arXiv. It's part of [AMS-LaTeX](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex).

Comment: AMS-LaTeX has been split in two on ctan and in tex live; the two parts are `amscls` (the classes and `amsthm`) and `amsmath'.